# What are the timings for double pulling in safe lane, and pulling from offlane?

Tags: dota-2

So I know the timing for pulling the safelane with the easy camps is XX:12 or XX:42, but if you want to double pull to one of the hard camps, then is there a best time to do this? Or does it depend on which easy camp you get and therefore how quickly the easy neutrals DPS down the creeps? (Note - you need to quelling blade or tango a tree to do this successfully in radiant jungle, think you can maybe get away with not doing it in dire jungle? Don't know for sure)

Secondly, what is the timing for offlane pulling the hard camp from dire jungle, and easy camp in radiant jungle? (Again, this requires tree consumption on both I think)

Thanks in advance!!

PS - unrelated helpful note for anyone interested in learning more about pulling - if you get the camps with the healing creeps, you have to aggro by walking into them, not attacking them, as the healing creeps will remain stationary and heal if any of their compatriots are below 100% health. This was a revelation to me so thought I'd share :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### For double pulling

No there is no particular timing.

**However I use a simple trick :**

To make a double pull, simply watch the amount of health remaining among the neutral creeps. You want to start pulling the second camp toward the first one when the total of health remaining among the neutral creeps is ~400. Of course this depends on the number of your creeps that died while fighting neutrals (if 2 or 3 died, you have to wait for less than 400HP). However this 400 total health is a relatively good indicator.

It's easier if you have a hero that can burst neutrals easily (like Shadow Shaman or Crystal Maiden) since when you come with the second camp, you can burst the remaining creeps thus moving the aggro of your creeps to the other neutrals. This burst allows you a better margin for error (e.g. you start pulling too soon and the creeps won't die in time, burst them when you come back with the other camp).

This is not a foolproof method since the aggro mechanic is hard to master and the fog of war can screw your aggro over. However this helped me a lot getting better double pull.

### For Radiant offlane pull

Start pulling when your creeps reach the tier 1 (furthest from base) tower. A bit sooner if the neutral camp is stacked.

### Finally

Only practice will makes you better. If you miss one timing, you know for the next wave if you have to pull sooner or later.

Comment: Great answer, thanks Wizliz, I'll bear this in mind! So you give a view of when to pull for Radiant offlane, but not Dire - does that mean it's not possible to pull Dire offlane? If not, why not? Is the other dire easy camp simply too far away from the lane?

Comment: @Cheeseburger There is no neutral camp that is clsoe enough to the lane to allow a Dire offlaner to pull neutral. A technique exists however and consist in blocking the lane with a EarthShaker's Fissure, forcing your creep to go toward the Dire Ancient Camp and pulling them on this camp. THis is really hard to pull off and not necessarily worth it.

Comment: once again, good knowledge!! Funny that there is a disparity between Radiant and Dire, though I suppose it party makes up for the Dire advantage over Roshan. Thanks again for the info!!